# How to count the no of lines in csv file using groovy function in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using Loop controller to iterate the csv file to fire the api requests. The number of loops equal to the number of lines in the CSV file. I am using groovy function to determine the number of lines.

[image: Loop Controller]

[image: CSV data set config]

However, when I run the test, it does not seem to read the csv file. I do have 3 apis listed in the csv file. I get the below console log

````
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor$1 (file:/C:/apache-jmeter-5.1.1_New/lib/groovy-all-2.4.16.jar) to constructor java.io.File(java.lang.String,java.io.File)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
summary =      0 in 00:00:00 = ******/s Avg:     0 Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err:     0 (0.00%)```

Any idea how do I fix this groovy function?
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The groovy function is fine:

[image]

Just in case here is the textual representation:

```
${__groovy(new File('C:/full.csv').readLines().size(),)}
```

Here is the referenced methods:

- [new File(String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.lang.String)) constructor
- [File.readLines()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#readLines()) function
- [List.size()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size--) function

It might be the case you're suffering from a [Jar Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell) caused by a clashing library originating from a shitty plugin somewhere in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) so try upgrading to vanilla [JMeter 5.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-5.3/) or whatever is the latest stable JMeter version available from [Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page and the issue should go away

If it doesn't - check whether your user has read permissions for the file, if not - you will need to [launch JMeter as administrator](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/run-as-admin)